# Create 1-bit bitmap from HTML Canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bitmap

I need to get a 1-bit bitmap out of an HTML5 Canvas.

The canvas is black-and-white.
However, I can only use toUrlData() with png/jpeg outputs, but can't find any way to generate a bitmap (and change the color depth to 1-bit).

Are there any available solutions for this type of conversion?
Or maybe a javascript library that can write a bitmap image?

Answer (score 12):

## Converting to 1-bit

There is no built-in mechanism for Canvas that allow you to save 1-bit images. Canvas is 32-bit (24 bit color, 8 bit alpha) and this would require the standard to use a common algorithm to degrade the image (which I likely why you can't save GIF files from it but only formats that support 24-bits or more).

For that you need to go low-level and build up the file format your self with [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

If 1-bit file *format* is not an absolute requirement, i.e. you want the image to *appear* as if it is 1-bit you can simply convert the content yourself.

You can use this method to convert an image to "1-bit" by converting RGB to luma values and use a threshold to determine if it should be "on" or "off":

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // Main code
  var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height),
      buffer = idata.data,
      len = buffer.length,
      threshold = 127,
      i, luma;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
    // get approx. luma value from RGB
    luma = buffer[i] * 0.3 + buffer[i + 1] * 0.59 + buffer[i + 2] * 0.11;

    // test against some threshold
    luma = luma < threshold ? 0 : 255;

    // write result back to all components
    buffer[i] = luma;
    buffer[i + 1] = luma;
    buffer[i + 2] = luma;
  }
  
  // update canvas with the resulting bitmap data
  ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
};

img.crossOrigin = "";
img.src = "//i.imgur.com/BrNTgRFl.jpg";
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=500 height=400></canvas>
```

[image: To 1-bit]

To save it as a BMP file (24-bits though and not supported by all browsers):

```
var bmp = canvas.toDataURL("image/bmp");
```

Also see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652307/canvas-unable-to-generate-bmp-image-dataurl-in-chrome/29652507#29652507)** for how you can build and write a BMP format yourself.

You can use this method also with a low-level approach by using the result from this to pack the bits (every 8 "bits" needs to be packed into a single byte, little-endian for BMP format).

Optionally look into the [TrueVision TGA file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) which is simpler, or the [TIFF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) which also allow you to use big-endian bytes (most TIFF formats can be read by browsers btw.).

Comment: Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf8Xf/61/) without the broken dependency.

Comment: Thank you @Jackson for the efforts (and for prompting the outdated code). I decided to instead inline the code which wasn't an option at the time the answer was originally written, as well as improve the general answer a bit (no pun).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a library like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). And write out the bitmap file manually by following the [BMP File Format specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

You'd do something like this with the resulting data:

```
function saveData() {
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
    var dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        dataView.setUint8(i, data.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    var blob = new Blob([dataView], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    saveAs(blob, "test.bmp");
}
```

You'd probably need to look up some info on [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) and [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/DataView) if you were to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the image to be 1bit (For POS printers for example):

```
// Function to convert a bitmap image to ESC/POS byte array
function convertBitmapToESCPOS(imageData, width) {
  const threshold = 128; // Pixel intensity threshold for monochrome conversion
  const bytesPerLine = Math.ceil(width / 8);
  const escposArray = [];

  // Resize the image to the specified width and convert to monochrome
  // You need to implement this part based on your chosen image processing library
  // For example: https://github.com/jimp-dev/jimp/

  // Iterate through each pixel and convert to ESC/POS commands
  for (let y = 0; y < imageData.height; y++) {
    let lineData = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < imageData.width; x++) {
      const pixelIndex = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
      const grayscaleValue = (imageData.data[pixelIndex] + imageData.data[pixelIndex + 1] + imageData.data[pixelIndex + 2]) / 3;
      const isBlack = grayscaleValue < threshold;
      const pixelBit = isBlack ? 0 : 1;
      lineData.push(pixelBit);

      // Once we have 8 pixels (1 byte), convert to a byte and push to the ESC/POS array
      if (lineData.length === 8) {
        const byteValue = lineData.reduce((byte, bit, index) => byte | (bit << (7 - index)), 0);
        escposArray.push(byteValue);
        lineData = [];
      }
    }

    // If there are remaining bits in the line, pad with zeros and convert to a byte
    if (lineData.length > 0) {
      while (lineData.length < 8) {
        lineData.push(0);
      }
      const byteValue = lineData.reduce((byte, bit, index) => byte | (bit << (7 - index)), 0);
      escposArray.push(byteValue);
    }
  }

  return escposArray;
}

// Example usage
const imageWidth = 384; // Width of the ESC/POS paper
const imageData = {
  // Replace with actual image data or load from a source
  width: /* image width */,
  height: /* image height */,
  data: /* image pixel data */,
};

const escposByteArray = convertBitmapToESCPOS(imageData, imageWidth);
console.log(escposByteArray);
```