# Raphael not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, raphael

I can use my raphael test page (just playing with it at the moment) in Firefox and IE 11 (eurgh). It doesn't, however, work in Chrome. I've checked the console and no errors have been reported, just the Raphael features won't work (adding a rect, image).

So, firstly:
1. Is chromes support for Raphael different to others?

Secondly, I'll post my code in case I've made a huge error somewhere (left out HTML as it's a basic DIV).

```
    //Get the background image
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = 'comp1.bmp';
var width = myImg.width;
var height = myImg.height;
var allShapes = [];

var paper = new Raphael("paper", width, height);
//Add a background image
var img = paper.image("comp1.bmp", 0, 0, width, height);

var cw = width / 2;
var ch = height / 2;

var allShapes = [];
var activeRect; //This will store the rect that was used last.

//drag and drop code
function addNewShape(){
    var rectDetails = {};
    rectDetails.rect = paper.rect(cw - 50, ch - 50, 50, 50);
    rectDetails.rect.attr({
        'stroke': 'orange', 
        'fill': 'white',
        'fill-opacity': 0,
        'stroke-width': 2
    });

    //Set the resizer for this rectangle
    var resize = paper.rect(cw - 20, ch - 20, 20, 20);
    resize.attr({
        fill: "orange",
        stroke: "none",
        opacity: .5
    });

    //Assign to rect
    resize.box = rectDetails.rect;
    resize.drag(move_resizer, start_resizer);
    rectDetails.rect.sizer = resize;

    rectDetails.rect.drag(drag_move, drag_start, drag_up);

    //Add co-ordinate text box
    var div = document.getElementById('coordContainer');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "Shape " + rectDetails.rect.id + ":   <input type='text' id='pos" + rectDetails.rect.id + "'>";

    //Add the new shape to the shape coords array
    allShapes[rectDetails.rect.id] = rectDetails.rect;  
}

function getCoords(){
    var coordDiv = document.getElementById('resultsContainer');
    for(var i = 1; i <= allShapes.length; i++) {
        var bbox = allShapes[i].getBBox();
        var temp = "Shape " + allShapes[i].id + ": X(" + bbox.x + "), Y(" + bbox.y + ")";
        coordDiv.innerHTML = coordDiv.innerHTML + temp;
    }
}

var ox = null;
var oy = null;

function drag_start(e) {
    //Set the active rect
    activeRect = this;
    //Assign attrs
    this.ow = this.attr('width');
    this.oh = this.attr('height');
    this.ox = this.attr('x');
    this.oy = this.attr('y');
    this.sizer.ox = this.sizer.attr("x");
    this.sizer.oy = this.sizer.attr("y");
    this.sizer.attr({opacity: 1});
};

//Moving the shape
function drag_move(dx, dy, posx, posy) {
    document.getElementById("pos" + this.id).value = "X: " + dx + " | Y: " + dy; //co-ordinates of the shape!
    this.attr({
        transform: "...T" + (dx - ox) + "," + (dy - oy)
    });
    this.sizer.attr({x: this.sizer.ox + dx, y: this.sizer.oy + dy});
    // store the previous versions of dx,dy for use in the next move call
    ox = dx;
    oy = dy;    
}


function drag_up(e) {
    //reset the original positions
    ox = 0;
    oy = 0;
}

function start_resizer(){
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("x");
    this.oy = this.attr("y");        

    this.box.ow = this.box.attr("width");
    this.box.oh = this.box.attr("height");   
}

function move_resizer(dx, dy){
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
    this.box.attr({width: this.box.ow + dx, height: this.box.oh + dy});
}
```

NB:
The addShape() function is called from a button. 
Chrome shows the div, just it's content is empty (white).

I have no idea what the issue is with this code. Any help greatly received.

Comment: Have you tried with a non .bmp background ? (*chrome seems to have some bmp issues https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449489 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=176678 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652307/canvas-unable-to-generate-bmp-image-dataurl-in-chrome*)

Comment: I'll try that now :) - Tried it and the result was the same using a jpeg :(

Comment: Changed the position of the shape and I can add it, which indicates its an issue with adding the image. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli if you put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: So any idea yet what the real issue is with chrome. I currently have the same problem with raphael.js and chrome!!!