# Converting a png/jpg to .ico in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ico

So i want a tool that generates a `.ico` file from a jpg/png. 
I have generated the jpg from a canvas using this code:

```
var img    = c.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Which takes from this canvas:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="16" height="16">
```

So the qustion is; is it possible to convert the generated png to a ico?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/twolfson/7656254 but you still need to do your homework on that

Comment: Here is a library wich do the work https://github.com/egy186/icojs

Comment: @Angel this seems to be the inverse (ICO to PNG/JPG)? The OP requested something to convert from PNG/JPG to ICO.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox you can do this directly from canvas:

```js
// Make ICO files (Firefox only)
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.arc(c.width>>1, c.height>>1, c.width>>1, 0, 6.28);
ctx.fill();

c.toBlob(function(blob) {
  console.log(blob)
}, 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', '-moz-parse-options:format=bmp;bpp=32');
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=32 height=32></canvas>
```

otherwise, to support other browsers you will have to build the ico file manually. See [format description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) and for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29652507/1693593) on how you can do that.