# How can I convert any image format to .ico format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This code upload image files and preview it and convert it to .ico format
I run this code but it didn't work.Image just converted to .png format
.So,can someone show me mistake

```js
function $(query){
    return document.querySelectorAll(query);
}
var btnUploadImage=$(".btn input")[0];
var canvas=$("canvas")[0];
var image=new Image();
var reader=new FileReader();
var btnDownload=$(".btn-download")[0];
canvas=canvas.getContext("2d");
btnUploadImage.onchange=function(){
    if(btnUploadImage.files&&btnUploadImage.files[0]){
        reader.readAsDataURL(btnUploadImage.files[0]);
    }
}
reader.onload=function(){
    image.src=reader.result;
    canvas.canvas.width=image.width;
    canvas.canvas.height=image.height;
    canvas.drawImage(image,10,10);
    btnDownload.href=canvas.canvas.toDataURL("image/x-icon");
}
```

Comment: In Firefox you can do this directly from canvas:
<br />
[Link to Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48311295/11812450).